# User location in database

Tags: database, angular, laravel, geolocation

first of all I would like to clarify that I am not very professional in laravel or angular. I am trying to make a simple application in which I keep user ads. And I have no idea how to implement geolocation. With geolocation I mean the location of the user. I do not know if it would be better to save only the coordinates or the address in the database. What I'm looking for with this is when I show the ads of the users, I also get what part of the world they come from. And also be able to do searches from the location (Ads closer to the user or distant)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up Places API, Maps Javascript API and autocomplete API provided by google. It has everything you want for user address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I do store in database? Only coordinates?

Comment: Depending on what you want, you can get a lot of info from the API such as address components (country, state, city), formatted address etc.

Comment: But i don't want to depend on other apis. If it's necessary build my own location database.

Comment: The database is and should be yours own. The API only provides you information to store in your own database.

Answer (score 0):

You could store coordinates for the user. That's pretty much all you would need to do. All maps API's have a radius search feature that allows you to search within X miles or kilometers of a given coordinate. After you have your user's coordinates and know the coordinates of where your ads are relevant, you can then do a query to determine if the user is within the ad's reach.

If you want to simplify things a bit and not have to make a ton of API calls each time a page is loaded, you could simply assign a region to each user when they store their address. And then for each ad, you would assign the regions where you would like to show the ad. For example, if a 
user is in region=USA and the ad is relevant for region=[USA,Canada,Mexico], then the user would see the ad. I don't know how granular you need to get, but this would most likely be the simplest implementation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If i choose the coordinates method, I've have to get them in the client or the backend?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. At some point, you will have to use an API to "get" the coordinates from an external service. Once you have the coordinates, you can either store those or you can just store a region related to those coordinates, that's up to you. If you are trying to accomplish this without an API, I would say it's not really possible. Unless you used a regional method and assigned each country/city/state to its own region. In that case, you would not rely on an external API but it would still be a lot of work to set up.